# Why do I get down vote when I up vote something?

Tags: discussion, support

Today I just saw a notification telling me that I got down vote. I looked for it, and I found that it was my up vote that made down vote.

It was really frustrating, because it shouldnt happen this, because the up and down votings is supposed to be a personal discion. **Why when I down vote or up vote something, I get down votes?!** It doesnt seem faire, in my point of view, **but why is that?**

Comment: What sort of notification? So far as I'm aware, SE never pushes a notification on downvotes.

Comment: @goldPseudo Then how come I got the message that I got a down vote for an up vote of mine?! Its really weird.

Comment: @goldPseudo Actually, I only get red colors as notifications...

Comment: If people missuse their right to vote by randomly downvoting posts without any kind of penalty they might go on doing this. I don't think this is unfair, as if enough people agreed on the same qualifcation of a vote you'll get back your "lost" reputation. Also IMO it is only fair to get -rep if you cause another person a -rep because the user is supposed to have made some effort writting his post which you have downvoted.

Answer (score 2):

You get -1 rep when you downvote an answer. You do not get any loss of reputation for upvoting. See https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation